# Change in volume reading; thermal expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

A question puts forward a cylindrical container of cross-sectional area A, and coefficient of linear expansion α, filled by a liquid upto height h.

It asks you to calculate the height of the liquid level as shown by the scale on the vessel, on a rise in temperature of ∆θ.

The scale markings are made on the container walls, and the container expands, but the liquid does not.

The answer is h(1 -3α∆θ).

This diagram  sums up how (I think) this works;
[image]

If h units was the initial liquid length, the liquid length measured in the new units, say H;

New value H = (h units) - (increment in length, in new units)

As can be seen from this diagram, hα∆θ, in its case, is not the term to be subtracted, as it's in the old units. The conversion factor can be obtained as;

'h' units in the old units = 'h' units in the new units

Stating this in the old units;
$$h = h(1 + α∆θ)$$
So the conversion factor is $$1 new unit = 1 old unit(1 + α∆θ)$$

From that, the new value (measured in new units) is;
$$ H = h - hα∆θ(1 +α∆θ)$$
 Why isn't this so?

Comment: Does the scale expand?  Does the liquid?

Comment: The container has the scale markings on it, and it expands, but the liquid doesn't. Sorry, I'll add that in.

Comment: Doesn't the cross sectional area also expand?

Comment: Guess it does, the question just says the container expands. So yeah.